# Hashmap update all values respect to last item

Tags: java, hashmap

I am trying to store one key with multiple values. Firstly, I read some strings in text file,then split and finally try to store. **The problem is that when I try to store each of student with their courses,my studentByForCourseName hashmap updates everytime all the values(courses) with the last adding item.So,it looks like every student take the same courses with last student in my map.How can I fix this ?**

```
List<String> course_names = new ArrayList<String>();
    Map<String, List<String>> studentByForCourseName = new HashMap<String, List<String>>(); 


      ...  try {
            FileReader fr = new FileReader(file);
            br = new BufferedReader(fr);

            String line;

            while( (line = br.readLine()) != null ) {
                System.out.println(line);
                char[] chr_line = line.toCharArray();
                String word="";
                String tmp = "";

                if(course_names.size()>0)        
                        course_names.clear();

                for(int i=0; i<chr_line.length; i++) {

                    if(chr_line[i] == ':') {
                        student_names.add(word);
                        tmp = word;
                        word = "";
                        continue;
                    }

                   if( chr_line[i] == ',') {
                       course_names.add(word);
                        word = "";
                        continue;
                    }

                   if(i == line.length()-1) {
                       course_names.add(word);
                       word="";
                   }

                   word += chr_line[i];


                }

                studentByForCourseName.put(tmp, course_names);
            }...
```

and my txt file is that:

```
Ayse Kara:MATH101,CSE100,MATH259
Efe Anıl:BLAW203,MATH101
Suat Ali Barut:STAT253,MATH259
Nil Girgin:MATH259,HIST111,STAT253
```

Comment: There are also a MultiMap implementations in [Guava](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/23.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Multimap.html) and [Commons Collections](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/apidocs/org/apache/commons/collections4/MultiValuedMap.html), that associate multiple values to single key, and they might be simpler for your use case than manually managing lists of values for each key.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you call

```
studentByForCourseName.put(tmp, course_names);
```

you are not putting a copy of the instance referenced by `course_names` in the `Map`. You are putting the reference itself.

Therefore, if `course_names` keeps referencing the same `ArrayList<String>` instance (as it currently does), all the keys in your `Map` will have the same value.

You should create a new `ArrayList` in each iteration of your loop.

Change

```
if(course_names.size()>0)        
    course_names.clear();
```

to

```
course_names = new ArrayList<> ();
```

Another alternative (instead of the above suggested change) is to create a copy of the `ArrayList` when you `put` it in the `Map`:

```
studentByForCourseName.put(tmp, new ArrayList<>(course_names));
```